# scripting with telnet and tee

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, telnet, tee

with

```
#!/bin/bash
telnet ipaddr port &

i=1
while [ "$i" -lt 3 ]
do
   (( i += 1 ))
   sleep 10
done
```

result:

> Trying ipaddr...
>       Connected to ipaddr.
>       Escape character is '^]'.
>       Connection closed by foreign host

fine, since bash scripts run in non interactive, so no stdin used, telnet close immediately.

however if I add tee to redirect the result, like

```
telnet ipaddr port | tee -a out.txt &
```

the telnet service could run and get output. but what is the difference tee made? i expect the telnet will terminate immediately as well.

Comment: Handwaving: I believe it's due to the pipe, not `tee` specifically. Without the pipe, `telnet` doesn't have a proper stdout, but it has with the pipe.

Comment: but telnet terminates due to no stdin instead of no stdout, no?